# git - commited and merged changes show up as unstaged in local branch

Tags: git

One of my co-workers added a new SQL table for us to use, and it's since been committed and merged into `master` for our database repository. I have my local one up-to-date and all, but for some reason `git` keeps it as an unstaged change. Even when I go to stash it (and override it later), or lose it when I force a checkout to another branch so I can do work, it keeps coming back.

It's not exactly a problem since I don't include it when I stage my commits, but I don't want to have to keep accommodating for this. None of my co-workers know how to fix this issue, and I think one tried deleting his local repository and cloning it again, but it still didn't work. Does anyone know the cause and how to undo this?

Have a picture (blocked some personal info)
[image]

I've tried `git stash`, `git checkout -- .` (to delete it), `git checkout -f <branch>`, but none of those worked, the file always comes back.

We both are on Windows 10.

Comment: Please show the output of `git status` and the also the commands you actually ran to try to fix this problem.

Comment: Also, please tell us your operating system, and the operating system of the person who checked in the change. This might be a CRLF issue, in which case those operating systems and your (and their) [relevant `git config` values](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#_formatting_and_whitespace) might be helpful for diagnosis.

Comment: Can you share the output of `git diff` on this file?

Comment: git reset --hard must do the trick ;)

Comment: I just checked our repository and we have 2 files with very similar names, one doesn't have all caps, though. Maybe git is confused with which one is which?

Comment: On windows this might be an issue as names are case insensitive

Comment: Yeah, it's trying to override the changes of one of the tables with the other :(. Why would it consider it an unstaged change when I never touched this file?

Comment: git reset --hard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just checked our repository and we have 2 files with very similar names, one doesn't have all caps, though. Maybe git is confused with which one is which?

It's not so much *Git* being confused, as the fact that on your OS / file-system combination, you literally *cannot* store both files.

If you create a file named `ReadMe.txt`, and then ask your OS to create another, different file named `README.TXT`, your OS refuses to do that.  Instead, it just overwrites `ReadMe.txt` with the new content.

*Commits*, in Git, are not files.  While they do *contain* files, they store them in a special, read-only, Git-only, frozen format, that your OS does not use or understand.  This format can hold both files—the one whose name ends in all-uppercase and the one whose name ends in mixed-case.

Git is extracting both files, and your OS is keeping only *one* of them.  Git realizes that your OS cannot keep both out at the same time, but Git cannot do anything about that.  (It *could* warn you about this, at the least, and very recently, Git has learned to do that.)

The way to fix this is to make a new commit in which the files have clearly-different names (or in which there is only one file with the two names that your OS thinks is one name).  The *easiest* way to do that is to do it on a computer, or file-system, that can store both names.  For instance, if you have a Linux machine handy, clone the repository there, shuffle the files around, commit, and push.  The new commit stores the files under the new improved names.  Be careful not to check out the old commit that has the two files under the names that overlap on Windows.

Comment: Yeah, I'm also worried about them confusing the tables, it seems like they were made separately but they didn't realize they had the same names. I'll talk to them about changing the name.